# Page loading taking too much time

Tags: joomla, load, html, joomla3.0

i have joomla view where i am including 4 more sub template views

```
   <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('Market_1'); ?>
   <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('Market_2'); ?>  
   <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('Market_3'); ?>
   <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('Market_4'); ?>
```

and every template file taking too much time to load because every file displays 15 tables with text and images...

and page load when all templates loaded and its taking too much time is there any way to load some fast? or first load 'Market_1' and others one by one and page open in quick time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. I cannot think of any reason why you would want to display that much data at once that it actually "overloads" the page.

But to address your question. No. In php you cannot asynchronous load the templates. To do that you should implement some kind of Ajax (javascript).

But again... You really need to reconsider your solution imo.